# Tasker Exported App Javascriptlet Error

Tags: javascript, tasker

I have created a Task to get the JSON result from 500px using HTTP GET and then used Javascriptlet code:

```
var arr=JSON.parse(global('HTTPD'));
var name=arr.photos[0].name;`
```

To parse the JSON result, everything is working fine when run from the TASKER.
But after exporting it as an APP, it gives error on `JSON.parse()`:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I tried using .js file also. Can't figure out what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I would use javascriptlet in following way.

```
url = "your url here.";
http = newXMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET",url,false);
json = eval("("+http.responeText+")");
yourvariablename = json.var[0].name;
```

Also i do an variable set before the javascriptelet task.
for example. @variable set to ...

then set that @variable to some value within json.